# In Sublime text 3, with handlebar files, how can I turn on css autocomplete?

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm working in an Ember.js HBS template - handlebars.

I've got bootstrap less files with my styles in them.

I'd *love* to be able to turn on autocomplete for the styles, anyone know how to do so?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Are you trying to get completions for your `.less` files? If not, what is the extension of the files you're trying to get completions in, and what syntax highlighting language are you using for them? Look in the bottom right of the editor window to find out. If it's from a plugin you installed, please give the URL of the plugin.

Comment: I am trying to get the styles that my less files will end up generating to complete when I am editing Handle Bars files.  Currently, I'm using the handlebars plugin for sublimetext [Linked Here](https://github.com/daaain/Handlebars)